CS50P-problem set 7-working 9 to 5-pytest exit code
I don't know why it's showing the exit code for test_working.py is 2. Please see the screenshot for the error message I got from check50: 
Both file works well on my end...
I ran "pytest test_working.py" on my end and all tests passed
Can somebody please help me? Thanks!
Here is the "working.py":
import re
import sys


def main():
    try:
        print(convert(input("Hours: ").strip()))
        sys.exit(0)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)



def convert(s):
    matches = re.search(r"^(1?[0-9]):?([0-6][0-9])? (AM|PM) to " \
                    r"(1?[0-9]):?([0-6][0-9])? (AM|PM)$", s)
    if not matches:
        raise ValueError("ValueError")
    else:
        from_hour, from_min = matches.group(1), matches.group(2)
        from_meridiem = matches.group(3)
        to_hour, to_min = matches.group(4), matches.group(5)
        to_meridiem = matches.group(6)

        from_hour = convert_hour(from_hour, from_meridiem)
        to_hour = convert_hour(to_hour, to_meridiem)

        from_min = convert_min(from_min)
        to_min = convert_min(to_min)

        if ((from_hour == None) or (from_min == None) or
            (from_hour == None) or (from_min == None)):
            raise ValueError("ValueError")

        return f"{from_hour}:{from_min} to {to_hour}:{to_min}"



def convert_hour(h, meridiem):
    if 1 <= int(h) <= 12:
        if meridiem == "AM":
            if len(h) == 1:
                return ("0"+ h)
            elif h == "12":
                return "00"
            else:
                return h
        else:
            if h == "12":
                return h
            else:
                return f"{int(h) + 12}"
    else:
        return None



def convert_min(min):
    if min == None:
        return "00"
    elif 0 <= int(min) <= 59:
        return min
    else:
        return None



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Here is the "test_working.py":
import pytest
from working import convert, convert_hour, convert_min


def test_convert():
    assert convert("9 AM to 5 PM") == "09:00 to 17:00"
    assert convert("9:00 AM to 5:00 PM") == "09:00 to 17:00"
    assert convert("10 AM to 8:50 PM") == "10:00 to 20:50"
    assert convert("10:30 PM to 8 AM") == "22:30 to 08:00"


def test_convert_hour():
    assert convert_hour("9", "AM") == "09"
    assert convert_hour("12", "AM") == "00"
    assert convert_hour("12", "PM") == "12"
    assert convert_hour("1", "PM") == "13"
    assert convert_hour("13", "PM") == None
    assert convert_hour("0", "PM") == None
    assert convert_hour("0", "AM") == None
    assert convert_hour("13", "AM") == None


def test_convert_min():
    assert convert_min("60") == None
    assert convert_min("30") == "30"


def test_value_error():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("14:50 AM to 13:30 PM")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("9:60 AM to 5:60 PM")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("9 AM - 5 PM")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("09:00 AM - 17:00 PM")



Are you sure that is the actual content of test_working.py?  Are you sure you saved it?

Yes, I'm sure, I tried a couple of times both yesterday and today

According to the course documentation, the check50 program is supposed to include a url in its output you can visit to see the failure results in more detail.  Did you visit that url?

I kind of solved it by removing other "help functions" (convert_hour, convert_min) and just using the convert function in working.py. It works. BUT, I don't quite understand.. the problem set itself says we can implement other functions. Also, this is making my code super redundant..

Here's a guess why your solution worked -- I suspect check50 doesn't isn't aware of your helper functions and only uses from working import convert. Then you get an error when they are called. You can verify this by making convert_hour() and convert_min() as inner functions of convert(). Then they will be included with the imported function. Modify your pytest code appropriately after making these changes.
